# Does Self Duality imply Hamiltonicity?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

I just looked at some self dual graph examples in the web and found that all of them are hamilton.

> Are there non-hamiltonian self dual graphs, or does self duality imply hamiltoncity?

I have no idea, how to tackle this question. Thanks for your help...

**EDIT** Ok, I found this in *Alan Bruce Hill*'s thesis on [*Self-Dual Graphs*](http://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/10012/1014/1/ab2hill2002.pdf) in the "Conclusion and Open Problems" section:

> "For example, I conjecture that
>   all 3-connected self-dual graphs are Hamiltonian. One possible approach to that
>   conjecture might be trying to use the radial graphs of Section 2.3. For self-dual
>   planar maps, there is a chance of proving/disproving this using the fact that we
>   know how to construct all such graphs."

Was there any progress since 2002?

Comment: I think this paper gives counter-examples: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128975/MathSlov_48-1998-2_3.pdf

Comment: @MTurgeon oh, this we should tell Alan...can you draw an explicit example and post it? I'll accept it. Thanks so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [paper](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128975/MathSlov_48-1998-2_3.pdf) by Peter Owens, the following graph is a counterexample:

[image: octohedral_graph_modified]

This graph is constructed as follows: start with the octohedral graph and add a vertex for each face. Then join this vertex to the three vertices forming the corresponding face. (This construction is given at the beginning of Section 2 of the aforementioned paper.)